# WP7 browser hangs when returning after successful WebBrowserTask.Show

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I have a WP7 application that uses WebBrowserTask.Show to launch a page in the browser. The WebBrowserTask.URL value is escaped using Uri.EscapeDataString (there are multiple query string parameters in the URL) and the page is displayed correctly in the browser.

On WP OS 7.0, after leaving the browser, and then starting the browser again from the Start page, the page load progress indicator stops about half way and the page does not load correctly.

If the application is returned to and the WebBrowserTask.Show is used to launch the same page in the browser again, the browser load also hangs.

On WP OS 7.1, after leaving the browser and then starting the browser again, the page loads correctly.

Any insight into what the issue is with WP OS 7.0? Are there any fixes or work arounds? I have an important segment of users who won't be on Mango for a few months.

Comment: Maybe you should just use Uri.EscapeUriString instead of Uri.EscapeDataString. Are you escaping the entire string or just the parameter values? Have you verified that the URLs that you get open fine on your desktop machine?

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, @xyzzer. The WP OS 7.0 docs (.chm file) are clear that Uri.EscapeDataString is required. I foudn that to be true during development, since Uri.EscapeUriString is not successful for WebBrowserTask.URL. I am escaping the entire string: the URL is passed in from another source, so that's the easy thing to do. The unescaped URL opens fine in a desktop browser.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Uri.EscapeDataString() for the entire URL is the right method to use here. See for example:

```
string uriString =
    "https://www.google.com/search?gcx=w&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=test query";

string escapedDataString = Uri.EscapeDataString(uriString);
    "https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fsearch%3Fgcx%3Dw%26sourceid%3Dchrome%26ie%3DUTF-8%26q%3Dtest%20query"

string escapedUriString = Uri.EscapeUriString(uriString);
    "https://www.google.com/search?gcx=w&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=test%20query"
```

It seems like EscapeDataString completely breaks the URL by escaping everything including the "https://" prefix while EscapeUriString just escapes what needs to be escaped.

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapeuristring.aspx) you should "Use the EscapeUriString method to prepare an unescaped URI string to be a parameter to the Uri constructor.".

Personally - I had always only escaped the parameters of the Uri I was building, so for example if a parameter value included an ampersand - I could force escaping it instead of relying on EscapeUriString to know everything.

Apparently - "https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fsearch%3Fgcx%3Dw%26sourceid%3Dchrome%26ie%3DUTF-8%26q%3Dtest%20query" is not a valid URL.

*EDIT

I must have missed that WP7.0 only had a string URL property now obsolete on WP7.1 and that property indeed requires escaping the entire URL using EscapeDataString. I tried it in both project types - targetting 7.0 and 7.1 and did not notice any hang. The only difference was that 7.0 would always tombstone my app, while 7.1 would not. Perhaps there is some other code in your application that blocks when you come back from being tombstoned. Here is my code:

```
string uriString = 
    "https://www.google.com/search?gcx=w&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=test query";
string escapedDataString = Uri.EscapeDataString(uriString);

var wbt = new WebBrowserTask();
wbt.URL = escapedDataString;
wbt.Show();
```

Another idea - escape the uri string twice - first using the EscapeUriString call for entire address or calling EscapeDataString just for the parameters when building the string and then escape the entire resulting uri again using EscapeDataString.

Comment: That's correct, in WP OS 7.0 WebBrowserTask has a URL property; in WP OS 7.1 it has a Uri property and marks the previous URL property as obsolete. As I explained, the problem is not in returning to the application, it is in returning to the browser that creates a problem.

Comment: Since I don't see any hang when calling WebBrowserTask multiple times with that last code snippet - I would say there is still something wrong with your URL string or the web resource at that address.

Comment: Emulator only with projects targeting both 7.0 and 7.1.

Comment: Then that's not a very useful data point. As I pointed out in the question, the problem does not exist with the browser in 7.1. Testing in an emulator that supports 7.1 projects would not be expected to exhibit the problem. Thanks for your time all the same.